# Running a js file with node

Tags: javascript

Currently, you just log on to the ssh with putty.

We're trying to run a js file which then basically creates an empty log file, currently we're just getting this error:

> port : '1157', ^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16) at Module._compile (module.js:443:25) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10) at Module.load (module.js:355:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10) at startup (node.js:129:16) at node.js:814:3

Here's the code we think is the problem:

```
var mysqlInfo; 
mysqlInfo = { 
           host : https//www.random.com, port : '2332',      
           user : 'test@localhost', password : '32323232', 
           database : 'test_installation', 
           charset : 'utf8_general_ci' 
           };
```

we're not sure how to format it

Another problem is we get multiple connecting issues, but I think this is the main problem.

*details edited out for security, but same format as our actual file*

Comment: You might want to edit the code-sections for better readability.
Are both those ports free on your machine? I found on another topic that your extensions.js could be configured badly

Comment: @InsOp the ports are the same, I edited the bottom one for security, but forgot the top one... I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: You might show us where the error appears

Comment: @user3853755 did answer given work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which i noticed,

- first install mysql node module
- then require it in you js

the code which you wrote is for exporting module. and as per your question it seems you want to connect to mysql db.

please use the code given below and run it using **node connect.js** command it will work for you.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host : https//www.random.com, 
    port : '2332',      
    user : 'test@localhost', 
    password : '32323232', 
    database : 'test_installation', 
    charset : 'utf8_general_ci'
});

con.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});
```

Thanks
Amit